# Button needs double click to change?

Tags: javascript, button

I'm trying to make a a dropdown "menu" with buttons. The button changes from + to - depending if is displayed or not. The thing is that if I press one, its okay, but then when i press the other button it doesn't dropdown or change, just changes if I click twice. Code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #persona{
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        display: none;
    }
    #productes{
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        display: none;
    }
    button{
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 50px;
        border: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="b_persona" onclick="show_hide('persona','b_persona')">+</button>
<div id="persona">

</div>
<button id="b_productes" onclick="show_hide('productes','b_productes')">+</button>
<div id="productes">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var show_persona = true;
    var show_producte = true;

    function show_hide (id,b_id) {

        if(!show_persona){
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "+";
            show_persona = true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "-";
            show_persona = false;
        }

        if(!show_producte){
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "+";
            show_producte = true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "-";
            show_producte = false;
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
```

The problem basically is when i click one button and then the other. Any ideas? thanks guys!

Comment: Thats not the problem, I set the flag to the opposite coz when its displayed and clicks again, has to hide. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One call of `show_hide` will change values of both flags. However, property for only one `<div>` will be changed and it will be changed twice (in every `if` statement). Try this:

```
function show_hide (id,b_id) {

    if(id === 'persona'){
        if(!show_persona){
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "+";
            show_persona = true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "-";
            show_persona = false;
        }
    }

    if(id === 'productes'){
        if(!show_producte){
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "+";
            show_producte = true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "-";
            show_producte = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Now, the first time I click the button doesn't do anything, then the second does and it works fine. Solved the other problem, got a new one.. Thank mate!

Comment: @xinp4chi You're welcome ;) Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: Ill mark it as solved, coz I used ur model, changing it, changing the second if for an else statement and it works like a charm! Thanks!! PS: what do u mean with plunker? mark as solved and mark answer as useful?

Comment: @xinp4chi I mean [this](https://plnkr.co/), a good way to test code. Nevermind, great it works for you.

Comment: ill check that plunker thing! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Can be do in this way also

```
<button id="b_persona" class="all-btn" onclick="show_hide('persona','b_persona')">+</button>
<div id="persona"  class="common-class" style="background-color:yellow">

</div>
<button id="b_productes" class="all-btn" onclick="show_hide('productes','b_productes')">+</button>
<div id="productes" class="common-class" style="background-color:red">

</div>
```

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var show_persona = true;
    var show_producte = true;

    function show_hide (id,b_id) {

            var arrAllEle = document.getElementsByClassName('common-class');

            var arrAllBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('all-btn');

            for(var i =0;i<arrAllEle.length;i++){
                arrAllEle[i].style.display ="none";
            }

            for(var i =0;i<arrAllBtn.length;i++){
                arrAllBtn[i].innerHTML ="+";

            }

            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";

            document.getElementById(b_id).innerHTML = "-";

    }
</script>
```